# Cast to a class with a protocol as its generic type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I have several classes all conforming to a protocol called DataObject. I have another class that receives a generic type that also conforms to DataObject, e.g.:

```
protocol DataObject {
    func foo()
    //...
}

class A : DataObject {
    //...
}

class B : DataObject {
    //...
}

class C : DataObject {
    //...
}

class SomeClass<T: DataObject> {
    //...
}
```

Later in my code I have an object of type AnyObject that I need to cast to SomeClass. I don't know the specific type of the object inside SomeClass (and don't care). However, whenever I do:

```
var someClass = obj as? SomeClass<DataObject>
```

The compiler gives an error of what seems to be a crash in the compiling process - "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation Fault: 11".

Somewhere in the middle of the error details there's a call stack of the crash:

```
0  swift                    0x000000010fecb2b8 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
1  swift                    0x000000010fecb794 SignalHandler(int) + 452
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff87563f1a _sigtramp + 26
3  swift                    0x00000001112b0637 llvm::DenseMapAPIntKeyInfo::getHashValue(llvm::DenseMapAPIntKeyInfo::KeyTy const&) + 151
4  swift                    0x000000010f84db39 swift::irgen::emitWitnessTableRefs(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::Substitution const&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<llvm::Value*>&) + 329
5  swift                    0x000000010f8280be emitNominalMetadataRef(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::NominalTypeDecl*, swift::CanType) + 1310
6  swift                    0x000000010f81a3d4 getTypeMetadataAccessFunction(swift::irgen::IRGenModule&, swift::CanType, swift::ForDefinition_t) + 580
7  swift                    0x000000010f813526 swift::irgen::IRGenFunction::emitTypeMetadataRef(swift::CanType) + 54
8  swift                    0x000000010f7dca9f swift::irgen::emitClassDowncast(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, llvm::Value*, swift::SILType, swift::irgen::CheckedCastMode) + 143
9  swift                    0x000000010f89ac89 emitValueCheckedCast((anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction&, swift::SILValue, swift::SILType, swift::irgen::CheckedCastMode, swift::irgen::Explosion&) + 1065
10 swift                    0x000000010f894bfa swift::SILVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction, void>::visit(swift::ValueBase*) + 23626
11 swift                    0x000000010f88e39d swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 9901
12 swift                    0x000000010f7f8f4f swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 159
13 swift                    0x000000010f878c59 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::Module*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 2121
14 swift                    0x000000010f879693 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::SourceFile&, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, unsigned int) + 51
15 swift                    0x000000010f7b5087 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 6647
16 swift                    0x000000010f7b34e6 main + 1814
17 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff8db4d5c9 start + 1
```

I'm really stuck as I cannot use the object the way I should... Any explanations to why this happens, or better yet, any workarounds?

Comment: For a crash in the compiler you should always file a [radar](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Thanks, I did that. Any workarounds for the time being?

Comment: if you converted protocol DataObject to be class DataObject it will compile.

Comment: It in fact compiles after changing to a class, but then there's a new problem since casting to SomeClass<DataObject> fails for an instance of say SomeClass<A> (where A is a subclass of DataObject).

Comment: You can also do `var someClass = obj as? SomeClass`.  You don't need the bracket part on there unless you need to specify what type of `SomeClass` you're casting as...